# httrack No data seems to have been transfered with github url

Tags: command-line, web, download, mirroring, mirror

I am trying to get the following PR to view it offline.
The following  address `https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5982` is accessible from every one (no login is needed) but when I run the following code

```
httrack https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5982 -O ~/Sites/github/ -v
```

I get the following message:

```
mirroring https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5982 with the wizard help..
18:28:22    Warning:    Cache: damaged cache, trying to repair
18:28:22    Warning:    Cache: 0 bytes successfully recovered in 0 entries
18:28:22    Warning:    Cache: error trying to open the cache
18:28:22    Info:   No data seems to have been transfered during this session! : restoring previous one!
Done.
Thanks for using HTTrack!
```